# How To store user config for a gtk app

Tags: c, gtk, config

I want to write a simple text editor with GTK+ and I want  to store user config like font-size font-type etc...
I want write function like this:

```
char *fontName = "monospace bold 12";


char *getFont(something);



void setFont(char *fontName);
```

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: If you write it under Ubuntu, by default packages save their info in ~/.<appname>/config, you can parse this config, you can use raw data, or smth like xml or json, there are a lot of parsers for xml and json

Answer (score 6):

The default way of dealing with settings in the GTK+ world is using [GtkSettings](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/unstable/GtkSettings.html). Be careful this is not as straight-forward as one would think.

If you want something simpler, just store a [key-file](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Key-value-file-parser.html) in the [user config](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Miscellaneous-Utility-Functions.html#g-get-user-config-dir) directory.

Comment: Yeees that's what i need GKeyFile it's it's easier than xml file thanks

Comment: [Gtk.Settings](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/class.Settings.html)